# AttributeError: 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'private_fields' error message

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I don't understand what this error means. It appears that I did everything correctly.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import SignUpForm


class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUpForm
        fields = ['name', 'company', 'city', 'country', 'email', 'password']
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }
```

This will throw:

> **AttributeError: 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'private_fields'**

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import signup
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import signup

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = signup(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            post = register_form.save()
            message = format_html("Hi {0}, Thank you for signing up with us! See your profile <a href=''>{1}</a>".format(register_form.cleaned_data['name'], "here"))
            form = signup()
            return render(request, 'myapp/register.html', {'signup':NewForm, 'message': message})
        else:
            message = register_form.errors
            form = signup()
            return render(request, 'myapp/register.html', {'signup':form, 'message': message})

    else:
        form = signup()

    return render(request, 'myapp/register.html', {'signup':form})
```

Comment: Please share the definition of `SignUpForm` that is imported from `.models` and the full stack trace for the error. Also you are going to get into trouble using the same class name for two different things (`forms.SignUpForm` and `models.SignUpForm`).

Comment: Full traceback please..

Comment: Are you sure you need the parentheses on the end of `PasswordInput()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon He doesn't need them in this case, but it won't cause any problems if he does initialize the widget.  From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/): `The widgets dictionary accepts either widget instances (e.g., Textarea(...)) or classes (e.g., Textarea).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a model named `SignUpForm` is a really bad idea for a multitude of reasons.  Generally a class ending in `Form` should be a form class, not a model class.  More importantly, it is most likely the cause of your error.

In your `views.py` you are probably doing something like this:

```
from .models import SignUpForm
from .forms import SignUpForm

def some_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = SignUpForm(instance=SignUpForm(col1='foo', col2='bar'))
```

Guess what?  You just passed an instance of the `SignUpForm` **form** class to your `SignUpForm`, **not** the `SignUpForm` **model**!

Change the name of your `SignUpForm` **model**, and you most likely won't get errors.

If this didn't help please show me your `views.py` for this form.

Comment: Hi Caleb, I tried what you suggested but no luck. I posted my views.py in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @wpnewbie You didn't try what I suggested?  Your model, form, **and** view all have the same name!  Please try changing those names so that they are all unique and see if that works.

Comment: @wpnewbie also, after changing the name of a model, you will need to run migrations again.